# How to put the difference in timestamps into many sessions if the difference in timestamps not more than 5 minutes?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, timestamp, logical-operators

I have the Dataframe below, I am looking to create a new column called "session" in the Dataframe. If the user spent more than 5 minutes (5*60 = 300 second), the new session  will be created. The time spent (elapsed Time) for each user to move from screen to another screen is represented in the "delta" column in the Dataframe.

The Maximum session much be not more than 5 minutes (300 seconds).

This is the input:

```
df = 

        ip             screen           timestamp  \

0   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-08 17:54:53 
1   172.28.79.133           Messages 2020-11-08 17:54:56   
2   172.28.79.133               Chat 2020-11-08 17:54:57    
3   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-10 20:36:32  
4   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-10 20:37:01  
5   172.28.79.133           Messages 2020-11-10 20:37:04   
6   172.28.79.133               Chat 2020-11-10 20:37:07   
7   172.28.79.133           Messages 2020-11-10 20:37:09 
8   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-10 20:37:16
```

```
                          userId            delta  

0   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2              NaT  
1   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:03  
2   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:01 
3   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  1 days 23:31:39  
4   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:29 
5   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:03 
6   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 11:00:03 
7   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:02 
8   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:07
```

I want the Dataframe above to be like that after adding the session column:
This is expected output (The output which I am looking for):

```
         ip             screen           timestamp  \

0   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-08 17:54:53  
1   172.28.79.133           Messages 2020-11-08 17:54:56  
2   172.28.79.133               Chat 2020-11-08 17:54:57 
3   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-10 20:36:32   
4   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-10 20:37:01  
5   172.28.79.133           Messages 2020-11-10 20:37:04   
6   172.28.79.133               Chat 2020-11-10 20:37:07   
7   172.28.79.133           Messages 2020-11-10 20:37:09
8   172.28.79.133   DiscoverStudents 2020-11-10 20:37:16
```

```
                          userId            delta       session 

0   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2              NaT          NaT
1   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:03           1
2   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:01           1
3   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  1 days 23:31:39           1
4   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:29           2
5   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:03           2
6   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 11:00:03           2
7   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:02           3
8   0xSUpl8ge5SeLRvKHts8s7lEnlq2  0 days 00:00:07           3
```

This is the code:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime (df['timestamp']) 
df['delta'] = (df['timestamp']-df['timestamp'].shift())
df['time'] = df['delta'].dt.total_seconds()

for item in df['time']:
    if item <= 300:
       df['setion'] = 1
    else:
       df['setion'] = 2
```

Please note the number of sessions can be more than 3 sessions (unlimited number of sessions) based on the time taken for each user to move from screen to another screen.

I need really your help

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set which in addition to input, expected output, actual output includes all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to add your attempt. In addition, clarify the logic to be used in defining a session..

Comment: I worked on your comments, please check my question again

Comment: Please let me know if you have any more comments

Comment: I need to know what is the screens which the users visit for each session and how much time spent to move from a screen to another screen to know which screen the users are more interested in

Comment: This is just a part of my code, let me know if you want me to clarify any part of this code

Comment: @Thymen Is there anything is unclear in my question so I can explain it to you?

Comment: I updated the formatting of the question, so it is much easier to read. Also I don't think that we actually need all your columns, just the last one (`delta`) would have been enough, unless you care about this operation for distinct users (then we also need `userId`. Based on your data I would create a for loop and when I see a time delta larger than 5 minutes, increment the session id. Also I am not sure if you want this to work for a single user, or for multiple.

Comment: I want this to work for the multiple users. This is just an example of one user. The data pick up from a dictionary where the key is the "Ip" and "userId" and the value of this dictionary include the "timestamp" and "screen". so the first two line code should be for key,values in mhist.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(values).sort_values("timestamp")

Comment: so just do it for one user and it would be easier to do the same process for the other users

Comment: Yes, you need to increment the the session id when you see the time delta larger than 5 minutes which means if the timestamp larger then 5 minute will take the same session id number. You will start to increment the session id when you start a new session as you can see in my example above

Comment: For example, the first session will include the time delta --> 00:00:03, 00:00:01 and 23:31:39 ( this one is larger then 5 minutes) and the second session will include the time delta --> 00:00:29, 00:00:03 and 11:00:03 (this one is larger then 5 minutes) and so on

Comment: Is this clear to you?

Comment: If I understand your logic for updating the session count . You are saying if the total timedelta from the session start until session end < 5 mins.  Is this correct?  In your example, there seems to be an error in that the session for line 6 should be 3 not 2 as indicated.

Comment: Sorry for confussion. The session will end if the timedelta more then 5 minutes, otherwise the session won't be end. line 6 is correct bacuse the session start when the timedelta is "00:00:29" and end when the timedelta is "11:00:03" because "11:00:03" is more than 5 minutes. This means that the section start and close not based on the total timedelta, but based on each seperate time delta.

Comment: for more explaination, the second section start when the timedelta is "00:00:29 " (less than 5 minutes) and continute because the timedelta is  "00:00:03" (less than 5 minutes) and then the session is end when the timedelta is "11:00:03" (more than 5 minutes). After this point the third session is started.

Comment: @itprorh66 is this clear to you now?